How to Add a Private Docker Registry with Self-Signed Certificates to k3s Without Restarting k3s?
I am currently running a k3s cluster, which uses containerd as the container runtime. I need to add a private Docker registry to the cluster that uses self-signed certificates. However, I'm unable to restart the k3s service or the container runtime (containerd) as it would disrupt the running workloads.
I've tried adding the registry configuration and the certificates in the following locations:

Created the file /etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml with the registry details.

Placed the self-signed certificate in /etc/rancher/k3s/ca.crt.


However, these changes do not seem to take effect without restarting the k3s service or containerd.
Is there a way to dynamically load the registry configuration or the certificates into the k3s cluster without needing to restart it? Alternatively, are there other methods or workarounds to achieve this?
